# Define Foreign Key in SQL Lite using Azure Mobile apps client sdk

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

How can I define relation like foreign keys in sql lite while using azure mobile app client sdk. Following is my code.

```
public class Employee{  
  public string Id { get; set; }  
  public string FirstName { get; set; }  
  public string LastName { get; set; }  
  public string Email { get; set; }  
  public string Title { get; set; }  
  public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }  
} 

public class TimelineItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Author { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
}

var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("myStorage.db");
store.DefineTable<Employee>();
store.DefineTable<TimelineItem>();
```

But when I run the code and examine the database then instead of creating a relationship between two entities it creates JSON type field named as Author. I have tried one to many relationship and foreign key attribute but nothing worked.
I am using DB browser for SQL lite to examine the database.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per microsoft team relations are not supported in mobile sdk. For more details
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/444